# Visa Sponsorship not part of job offer, but I'd like to negotiate that

Tags: software-industry

While on the hunt for prospective employment, I noted some positions that I liked a lot, but, unfortunately, they were located outside of the country I live in (and hold citizenship of) and did not explicitly mention visa sponsorship packages. Some of them had relocation help as part of the benefits provided, and some had neither visa nor relocation packages mentioned.

I still want to apply to these positions, but I want to make it clear to prevent any confusion that I will likely require additional help in the process (even if it as much as having a job offer in a form I could present during the visa interview).

I understand that the cost of visa sponsorship is quite high, and thus am wondering how willing the average company would be to agree to such a request for other concessions, and what concessions might increase my chances.

So, to summarize the question - how reasonable would such a request be from the company's point of view, provided I fit the requirements mentioned in the job posting?

**Edit:** the country I am from is Russia, and the countries which I'm considering include the UK, France, Germany and Australia.

**Edit 2:** As it is apparently unclear what I am asking, here's an even more abridged version of the question: how does a company determine whether a request for visa sponsorship, which is not normally offered by that company, should be granted and what does it take into consideration?

Comment: Are you asking: how reasonable is it to ask this question? Or, are you asking: How reasonable is it for the employer to sponsor me, once I've asked? Also, you may want to include the countries you're applying for jobs in, and your own country, as it may influence the answer.

Comment: @dwizum The latter. I'm more or less certain that "there's no harm in asking" when it comes to job negotiation.

Comment: Employers are engaged in risk management when they hire a new employee. When they advertise a role they process candidates by rejecting everyone until they have just a few they're interested in. At that point they're looking for reasons to hire one of them. If you want to *compel* an employer to sponsor you. It's far easier to get a referral into the company to someone who has the power to hire and sponsor you. Following the traditional role of submitting applications to advertised non-VISA roles would seem more like waiting for luck. I might be wrong by the way. I've never worked abroad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea of your background, because it all depends on your **skill sets** and your **bargaining power**.

In academics (e.g. computer scientist at PhD level), visa sponsorship is awfully common. That make sense because the job is really not something that everybody can do.

In IT, you will need have very strong background history to convince visa sponsorship. UK, France, Germany and Australia have enough candidates for entry to middle level positions. You will need to prove yourself (more likely a senior position). If you did have the skills set, consider headhunters. Headhunters work with top clients (e.g. investment banking), those companies will more than happy to sponsor you if they believe you are unique.

**Answer**

You are free to ask for visa sponorship for any job position that you are qualfiied. However, expect rejection unless you have strong unique skills not available in the local market.